FileNotFoundError in Python when trying to access a file with relative paths on Windows
I'm encountering a FileNotFoundError when trying to access a file using relative paths in Python. My project structure is as follows:
C:\\Users\\danie\\CAMP-data-processing\
├── data\
│   └── experimental\
│       └── InputFastas\
│           └── combined_proteins_IUPRED.fasta
├── steps_combined\
└── combined_3_4.py  # This is the script I'm running

Full Paths:
The script I'm running is located at:
C:\\Users\\danie\\CAMP-data-processing\\steps_combined\\combined_3_4.py

The file I'm trying to access is located at:
C:\\Users\\danie\\CAMP-data-processing\\data\\experimental\\InputFastas\\combined_proteins_IUPRED.fasta

What I've Tried:
I'm attempting to use a relative path to access the file. Below is the code I'm using to construct the path and check if the file exists:
import os

root_directory = "../data/experimental/"
filename = "combined_proteins_IUPRED"
fasta_filename = root_directory + "InputFastas/" + filename + ".fasta"

# Print the path to verify
print(f"Checking path: {fasta_filename}")

# Check if the file exists
if os.path.exists(fasta_filename):
    print("File exists!")
else:
     print("File does NOT exist.")`

Output:
When I run this code, I get the following output:
Checking path: ../data/experimental/InputFastas/combined_proteins_IUPRED.fasta
File does NOT exist.

However, the file definitely exists at this location:
C:\Users\danie\CAMP-data-processing\data\experimental\InputFastas\combined_proteins_IUPRED.fasta
Using forward slashes (/) instead of backslashes (\) for paths in Python.
Using os.path.join() to construct the file path to ensure that slashes are handled correctly across different operating systems.
Checked for typos or case sensitivity issues in the directory and file names.
Printed the full path to verify it, and it looks correct: ../data/experimental/InputFastas/combined_proteins_IUPRED.fasta.
Absolute Path:
When I manually specify the absolute path like below, it works perfectly:
fasta_filename = "C:/Users/danie/CAMP-data-processing/data/experimental/InputFastas/combined_proteins_IUPRED.fasta"

if os.path.exists(fasta_filename):
    print("File exists!")
else:
    print("File does NOT exist.")

With the absolute path, I get:
File exists!
Question:
Why does the relative path not work in this case, and how can I resolve the FileNotFoundError when using relative paths on Windows?

Why are you using ../data? According to the file layout in the question, that folder is in the same place as the python script file; it is not one level up.

The most reasonable assumption is that you're running Python from a different working directory.
If you wish to use file paths relative to a Python file, use __file__ like so:
import pathlib
print(pathlib.Path(__file__, "../", root_directory, filename).exists())

